# Calculate r-squared between two columns for multiple files in a folder and write results to a single file using R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have multiple .txt files in a folder, each having multiple columns. I want to calculate r squared value between col 2 and 7 of each file and print the same into one output file. I tried following for one file and it works:

```
y<- read.table("A4GALT_BLCA.txt", sep ="\t", header=T)
x<-lm(y[,2]~ y[,7])
summary(x)$r.squared
```

When I try to do it for all files using apply or for loop, it doesn't work.

with for loop:

```
filenames <- list.files("trial", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {y<- read.table(filenames[i], sep ="\t", header=T) 
+ x<- lm(y[,2] ~ y[,7]) 
+ out<-summary(x)$r.squared
+ write.table(out, "test_out.txt", sep="\t")
+ }
```

This gives one file as output but has only one value in it (for the last file). How can i improvise it to have values from all the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the file each time through the loop, which is why you're ending up with just one row at the end. You could append a new row to the file each time (using `append=TRUE`) instead of overwriting it, but it's probably better to create a data frame of all the r-squared values and write it to a file once.

Also, you don't need to use `lm`. For two variables, the r-squared is just the square of the correlation coefficient.

```
corr.data = data.frame(rsq=rep(NA,length(filenames)), file=rep(NA,length(filenames)))

for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  y <- read.table(filenames[i], sep ="\t", header=T) 
  corr.data[i,1] <- cor(y[,2],y[,7])^2
  corr.data[i,2] <- filenames[i]
}

write.table(corr.data, "test_out.txt", sep="\t")
```

You could also use `lapply` instead of an explicit loop:

```
corr.data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
  y <- read.table(f, sep ="\t", header=T) 
  data.frame(rsq=cor(y[,2],y[,7])^2, file=f)
})

corr.data = do.call(rbind, corr.data)

write.table(corr.data, "test_out.txt", sep="\t")
```

**UPDATE:** In reference to your comment, here, for example, is how you'd get the r-squared for every pair of numeric columns in each file and save them to a new file.

```
library(reshape2)

corr.data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {

  y <- read.table(f, sep ="\t", header=T) 

  # Remove non-numeric columns
  y = y[ , sapply(y, is.numeric)]

  # Calculate r-squared between every pair of columns
  y = cor(y)^2

  # Keep only upper triangle of r-squared matrix
  y[!upper.tri(y)] = NA

  # Melt to long format and remove NA
  y = na.omit(melt(y))

})

corr.data = do.call(rbind, corr.data)

write.table(corr.data, "all_r_squareds.txt", sep="\t")
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one works perfect. the lapply throws an error :  Error: unexpected symbol in:
"}
corr.data".  lapply code doesn't end at curly bracket.  I m unable to figure out why. Please explain

Comment: I forgot to add the final close-parenthesis. Fixed now. Always a risk when you're writing code without an example to run it on. Hopefully that's the only error.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. could you explain  what following command does: 'corr.data = do.call(rbind, corr.data)'

Comment: `lapply` returns a list. Take a look at the output of the `lapply` code to see its structure. Each list element in this case is a data frame with one row. We want to stack all those single-row list elements into one data frame. `do.call` applies a function (`rbind` in this case) over a list. So in this case `do.call` runs `rbind` on the entire list, returning a single data frame. For example, after running `corr.data=lapply...`, do this: `rbind(corr.data[[1]], corr.data[[2]])`. This returns a data frame with two rows. `do.call` here does the same thing with every element of `corr.data`.

Comment: couple of questions: 1) show can I modify it if I need to look at r square values of say 2nd col with 8th onwards all columns individually. 2) what if I need residuals in this output.

Comment: See updated code showing how to get r-squared between all columns. If you want residuals, then you can go back to using `lm`. The object returned by `lm` stores the residuals. You can extract those and store them in a R object and/or write them to a file using techniques similar to those in my answer.